# Is there a simple way to handle key doesn't exist in python for loop?

Tags: python

Given the following code:

```
for bar in myDict['foo']:
```

Is there a simple way to handle key not found error?

I am already aware of using

`myDict.get('foo', defaultValue)`

Can I use that here? What would I return? None is not iterable.

I am also aware that I can precede the loop with

```
if 'foo' in myDict:
```

Is there something I can just do in the for loop declaration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need an empty iterable just return the (`[]`) empty list:

```
for bar in myDict.get('foo',[]):
```

Comment: As soon as I saw this answer, I felt instantly stupid.

Comment: @user602525: Worry not! :D Python make us feel that way sometimes ;)